# Basis of a 2 dimentional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $T: V \rightarrow V$ be a linear operator on a vector space of dimension 2. Assume that $T$ is not multiplication by a scalar. Prove that there is a vector $v$ in $V$ such that $(v,T(v))$ is a basis of $V$, and describe the matrix of $T$ with respect to that basis.

Comment: When you tried the problem did you start with $\{v, T(v)\}$, then find conditions for it to be a basis, or did you do something else?

Comment: @FelixMarin: What do you mean?

Comment: I started with (v,T(v))

Comment: It would be great if you could edit your post to show what you tried.

Answer (score 3):

In any linear space, two vectors are linearly *dependent* iff one of them is a scalar multiple of the other one, so if for all $\,v\in V\;,\;\;\{v\,,\,Tv\}\;$ is linearly dependent , then for all

$$v\in V\;,\;\;Tv=\lambda v\;,\;\;\lambda\in\Bbb F=\text{the definition field}$$

and this can't be by assumption (in fact, you could even prove we don't need more than two different scalars, but who cares about this?)

Comment: What do you mean by " we don't need more than two different scalars" in last line?

Answer (score 3):

$V$ has dimension $2$, so any linearly independent set of $2$ elements forms a basis.  Since $T(x) \neq ax$, there exists $v$ such that $c_1 T(v)+ c_2 v = 0$ has only the trivial solution and so there exists a $v$ that makes the set $\{v, T(v)\}$ linearly independent.  You'd have to verify all this of course.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider $a_{0}\nu + a_{1}{\rm T}\left(\nu\right) = 0$. $a_{1}$ must be zero since otherwise ${\rm T}\left(\nu\right) = -\left(a_{0}/a_{1}\right)\nu$ which contradicts one of the problem asumptions. Then, $a_{0}\nu = 0\quad\Longrightarrow\quad a_{0} = 0$.

Then,
$a_{0}\nu + a_{1}{\rm T}\left(\nu\right)
 = 0
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
a_{0} = a_{1} = 0$.

$$
\Longrightarrow\quad
\color{#ff0000}{\large\left\{\vphantom{\LARGE A}\nu,{\rm T}\left(\nu\right)\right\}\
\mbox{is a base}}
$$